# How to fix error "google-service.json"

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

[image]

I encounter this error when adding more advertising SDK for Google's mobile device in my application. What to do to fix this. Help me

Comment: Error log clearly showing that your `google-services.json` file is missing. Now what's your expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com). Create new Android Project. Follow the steps and finally you will get a google-services.json file. Download it and move to the ~/app/ folder. That s it!

Comment: Great . Thank you